# What is the typical work-flow and skills/techniques required for someone working on Structuring Products?

Tags: options, option-pricing, structured-finance, structured-credit

Are there any Portfolio Optimization techniques (Markowitz, Prospect Theory, etc...), valuations and derivatives hedging techniques? What is a typical workflow and what should one master?